# log4cpp: Linux can't find the lib files

Tags: c++, linux, log4cpp

I download the log4cpp in my Linux and I use the commands below to install:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

After that, I can find the lib files below in the path "/usr/local/lib":

```
liblog4cpp.a
liblog4cpp.la
liblog4cpp.so
liblog4cpp.so.4
liblog4cpp.so.4.0.0
```

Then I tried to use the log4cpp in my cpp project, which is complied by gcc11.

But I got the error message:

```
Undefined reference to "log4cpp::Category::shutdown()"
```

I think it can't find the lib files. So I added `liblog4cpp.so` manually.

Now I got this error:

```
undefined reference to "pthread_key_create"
```

What should I do?

Comment: What command line arguments are you using to compile your project? Are you linking the library properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I got this error because the lib pthread isn't a lib by default. So we must add it manually for our project(for the IDE) or add it as a parameter when you compile(gcc -pthread). If everything's OK, we can find it in /usr/lib.

Answer (score 1):

log4cpp is C++ lib, I recommend configure and build it using the same C++ compiler

Comment: I think I do use the same c++ compiler.